# Laravel 5.1 special user role use auth method?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.1

I am building an app where users can upload a job where contractors can search for job and get in contact with new customers.

Now I have used laravel's standard Auth method to let users/client register, login and upload jobs. Now I want to build the contractor part of the app so my goal is a seperate registration and login and when the contractor logs in he can only browse the jobs and comment on jobs

Can I use laravel's Auth method to built this or what should my game plan be here?

### Edit 1: I am thinking about using something like this: https://github.com/Kbwebs/MultiAuth

Anyone has any experience with it? So I need to have a database users for my clients and a database Contractors but how do I register contractors? Do I make a new route,view and controller and write the create functien manually and use this MultiAuth method?

I figured out some of my routes it should look something like this:

```
// Authentication routes for users/clients
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');


// Registration routes 
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::get('contractor/auth/register', 'contractor\Auth\ContractorAuthController@getRegister');

Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
Route::post('Contractor\contractor/auth/register', 'Contractor\Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
```

and if this is possible how do I check if a contractor is logged in? I currently check if a user is logged in like this Auth:check()

Comment: Try defining "Abilities" to each user type: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization

Comment: PS: I would create a custom AuthController (that either extends or calls the  Laravel AuthController) to handle adding these abilities

Comment: If I do this can I use Laravel's functions, etc. for the registration and login? Can I do the fun stuff like Auth;check() for both "roles" the clients and contractors?

Comment: Yes. Then for a specific role do something like (Auth::check() && $user->can('whatever-role-specific-thing').

Comment: I am not sure I understand, are you talking about the Authorization method or the method where I would create a custom AuthController?